# Nu HTML Checker show "Possible misuse of aria-label." for the special structure

Tags: html, svg, accessibility, wai-aria

I designed some special structure for the project effect and set the `aria-label` attribute on the tag. But Nu HTML Checker tells me that **"Possible misuse of `aria-label`. "**

```
<h3 aria-label="Contact">
    <span aria-hidden="true" class="char-wrapper">c
        <svg class="char-svg char--c">
            <use xlink:href="#char--c"></use>
        </svg>
    </span>
    <span aria-hidden="true" class="char-wrapper">o
        <svg class="char-svg char--o">
            <use xlink:href="#char--o"></use>
        </svg>
    </span>
    <span aria-hidden="true" class="char-wrapper">n
        <svg class="char-svg char--n">
            <use xlink:href="#char--n"></use>
        </svg>
    </span>
    <span aria-hidden="true" class="char-wrapper">t
        <svg class="char-svg char--t">
            <use xlink:href="#char--t"></use>
        </svg>
    </span>
    <span aria-hidden="true" class="char-wrapper">a
        <svg class="char-svg char--a">
            <use xlink:href="#char--a"></use>
        </svg>
    </span>
    <span aria-hidden="true" class="char-wrapper">c
        <svg class="char-svg char--c">
            <use xlink:href="#char--c"></use>
        </svg>
    </span>
    <span aria-hidden="true" class="char-wrapper">t
        <svg class="char-svg char--t">
            <use xlink:href="#char--t"></use>
        </svg>
    </span>
</h3>
```

Am I use it wrong? How do I fix this warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**h1-h6 are accessible by default**, thats why the `aria-label` attribute is marked as "possible misuse".

If you want to show text only to screen readers, try this solution: https://css-tricks.com/inclusively-hidden/

On your code, this would look something like that:

```html
<h3 aria-label="Contact">
    <span class="sr-only">Contact</a>
    <span aria-hidden="true" class="char-wrapper">c
        <svg class="char-svg char--c">
            <use xlink:href="#char--c"></use>
        </svg>
    ...
</h3>
```

CSS:

```css
/* Hiding class, making content visible only to screen readers but not visually */
/* "sr" meaning "screen-reader" */

.sr-only:not(:focus):not(:active) {
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0); 
  clip-path: inset(50%);
  height: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap; 
  width: 1px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. If I use `.sr-only` and I don't need `aria-label` on the heading tags. I think the screen reader will read the content of `.sr-only`. I will try this way.